# Can you correct this “old English” quote?

Tags: early-modern-english, thou-thee-thy

There’s an “influencer” that came across my page who posted a quote (attributed to themselves) and I know it’s wrong but I’m not informed enough to know how wrong it is. I’m not going to do anything with the corrections but I gotta know!

> When thee thinketh thee are done, thee have just begun

Comment: I don’t (think it's Old English)! But I believe the influencer does, or believes it makes them sound more “enlightened”. I probably could have tagged it archaic or obsolete.

Comment: Thanks! I’m looking for an answer that would include the proper usage of thee, thou, and the suffix -eth. I’ve tried figuring it out on my own but pronouns have always been my language weakness!

Comment: I believe "when thee thinketh" was never correct in Old English, nor in Elizabethan English.  More likely would be "when thou think'st".  Some dialects (Quakers or so) may have used "thee" in place of "thou".  But likely no one used "thinketh" for the second person.

Comment: Thou is subject case, thee is the object case pronoun. Each *thee* above should be *thou*.

Comment: Calling it "Old English" is asking for trouble. You're dealing with Early Modern English here. The pronouns here should be "thou", as others have already pointed out, and the verbs should be "thinkest", "art" and "hast".

Comment: As I said, not super informed on the subject but I should have known better coming here . Thanks for all the help!

Comment: However, see this use of *thee* as the nominative. http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cpercy/courses/6362Yaswen2.htm

Comment: hwænne þu wenst þæt þu aert gedon, þu aert niewlice begunnen is my attempt an old English

Comment: Some modern Quakers, up until the last century, were in the habit of using *thee* as their sole second-person pronoun, but they didn’t use the incorrect *-eth* form.

Answer (score 45):

1. Note, although this language is "old," the [term "Old English"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) refers to a much older version of the language (or, arguably, an earlier language altogether).
2. A common misperception is that ca 17th-century usage always used "thee" and never used "you." If you find yourself transported back to Elizabethan England, you could certainly say "When you think you are done" with no anachronism (and be more polite too, since *you* is the more formal pronoun!).
3. The main issues with the quote are that it doesn't decline "thee/thou" or conjugate "think" or "hast" appropriately. "Thou" is the subject of the sentence; "thee" would be the right form if it were an object. "Thinketh" would be a third-person form, not second-person. And "have" is the appropriate form for "you," but not for "thou." A corrected version would be:

> When thou think’st [or *thinkest*] thou art done, thou hast just begun.

Comment: I suspect that that in EME the subordinate clause would be subjunctive, so _When thou think'st thou beest done_.

Comment: "thinks't" is surely not correct. The 2nd person singular ending is -st; there's no contraction there.

Comment: @jogloran Thanks for the catch; I had misplaced the apostrophe.

Comment: @ColinFine Surely it would be _thou be done_, not _thou beest_?  Is _beest_ recorded anywhere as a subjunctive version of _be_?  Honestly, I'm actually slightly leaning to _When thou think'st thyself to be done_.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Actually I'd probably go for "When thou thinkest thyself done" myself, but I could also imagine authors tweaking the tense for the sake of meter as suggested elsewhere. I kept quiet at Colin's suggestion, but I don't know that it *has* to go subjunctive. I'm not a Shakespearean scholar, but searching [Open Source Shakespeare](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/) for the word "when," I see several places where it could have gone subjunctive and didn't, e.g.:

Comment: "The fated sky gives us free scope, only doth backward pull our slow designs when we ourselves *are* dull" *All's Well That Ends Well* I.i.218

Comment: It's not wrong exactly, but you should likely use "to be" in both verbs: ...thou *art* just begun.

Comment: And anything pithy from that time should have good scansion as well. To make it balance right, you likely need "thinkest" specifically ("thinkst" messes up the emphasis) and to insert another word: "When thou thinkest thou art done, thou art truly just begun."

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: both are found. The OED say "(b) beest forms (2nd singular). 1500s–1600s beest, 1600s bee'st. Historically, these continue indicative forms, but apparently at least some early modern English texts prefer beest (rather than art) in syntactic environments that otherwise favour use of the subjunctive such as conditional clauses, as illustrated here. Similar use in conditional clauses is found later in south-western English regional varieties, but these also use beest regularly in the indicative." The examples given include Milton and Shakespeare

Comment: Wow, thank you @ColinFine - today I learnt.

Comment: Back in Elizabethan times, "you" was how printers printed what we currently spell "thou", but was actually spelt with a [thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)) "þou", but they didn't have such a type set letter in their European printing set, so they picked the letter "y" which they deemed closest to thorn. The printers won the spelling battle. So, the correct pronunciation of "you" back then is "thou", because it's the same word.

Comment: @Bohemian That is not correct. _Thou_ and _you_ were always different words, which were _þū_ and _ēow_ in Old English (real Old English, not Early Modern). In Early Modern English, _you_ was the accusative form of _ye_ (Old English _ġē_), and both were pronounced with a _y_ sound. You're probably thinking of how the article _ye_ (as in "Ye Olde Shoppe", not to be confused with the aforementioned pronoun) is an old spelling of _the_.

Answer (score 18):

I believe that this quote has been put together by a fraud with little knowledge of old English grammar.

In addition to any other corrections,  *thee are* should be *thou art*; *thee have* should be *thou hast*; *thee thinketh* should be *thou thinkest*. These are all part of old English pronoun declensions and verb conjugations.

> [Longman](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/582828/can-you-correct-this-old-english-quote)
> thou hast: old use a way of saying ‘you have’
>
> thou art: old-fashioned biblical a phrase meaning ‘you are’

> [Hymnary](https://hymnary.org/text/amid_the_trials_which_i_meet)
>
> Thou thinkest, Lord, of me;
> Thou thinkest, Lord, of me; ...

So the better version would be:

*When thou thinkest thou art done, thou hast just begun*

Comment: Something went wrong with site editing so there are two deleted versions of this answer visible to those with the appropriate privileges. Please ignore them

Comment: A tweak that I like even better (to maintain the trochaic tetrameter) would be "when thou thinkest thou art done, thou hast only just begun."  (It would be perhaps more true to the style to say "verily, thou hast just begun" but then you have to smudge "verily" into 2 syllables.)

Comment: You should clarify which "old English" you are correcting it to.

Answer (score 12):

This is my attempt at correcting it to Old English.

> hwænne þu wēnst þæt þu sīe gedon þu eart niewlice begunnen

Old English had not yet reversed the letters h and w in question words, so "hwenne" for "when".  OE had the first person pronoun þu.  The modern verb "think" was used only for the sense of "ponder", so I've used the verb "wenst", which has the meaning of "hold an opinion". I've use a subjunctive "sie gedon". The adverb "just" is a more modern borrowing from French, so I've replaced it with "niewlice" (newly), and I've used what I think is a reasonable use of "þu eart begunnen" "thou art begun" rather than using "have begun" from modern English.

Comment: I've CW'd this as I'm open to edits and improvements from those who know OE better.

Comment: Just based on German and Swedish, I'd probably switch *þu eart* to *eart þu*, but this is based on absolutely no knowledge of OE at all.

Answer (score 4):

Anton has correctly said that the verb is incorrectly declined but it is also true that the influencer has confused the second and third person singular forms of the verb. "Thinketh" is the third person singular form, not the second, so "When he (or she, or it) thinketh that he (or she, or it) is done he (or she, or it) hath only just begun" would be correct but "thou thinketh" would be as wrong as "you thinks"